# Embedded Youtube Video on ASP Webpage "An error occurred, please try again later"

Tags: asp.net, video, youtube

When I embed a youtube video of mine (using the share link) on my ASP.NET MVC 5 webpage, the video shows an error of "An error occurred, please try again later."

The Learn More link on the error from youtube simply says to wait 30 minutes, but the video works fine on Chrome.

The error I'm seeing occurs on IE (all versions) and Firefox.

Anyone else see this?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the browser not supporting the format - see this link for similar issues: http://www.ghacks.net/2014/06/13/fix-error-occurred-please-try-later-youtube-error/.